# Data Type conversion error in Pivot Table

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that stores our company's positions and "requirements". I.e. each position needs to have undergone a building induction, etc., etc. There's a program that allows the users to see/manage all this, but of course, someone wants an export for a client and it's not really possible with the current setup, I'm thinking a quick pivot table will get the job done though.

I have the following tables;

```
---------------------------
|        Positions        |
---------------------------
| PositionID   | int      |
| PositionName | nvarchar |
---------------------------

------------------------------
|       Requirements         |
------------------------------
| RequirementID   | int      |
| RequirementName | nvarchar |
| RequirementType | bit      |
------------------------------

-------------------------
| Position Requirements |
-------------------------
| Position_ID    | int  |
| Requirement_ID | int  |
-------------------------
```

What I would like to do is pull out the data for a specific **Position** or **Positions**, i.e. `SELECT * FROM Positions WHERE PositionName LIKE '%Manager%';`
These **Positions** would form the leftmost column of the **PivotTable**.
For the top row of the **PivotTable**, I would like to have each **RequirementName**.
The internal data would be the **RequirementType** field (i.e. '0' or '1', maybe 'Any' / 'All').

I've read and read and read, but I can never quite seem to get my head around the concept of them, so this is my current attempt;

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Requirements
PIVOT (MAX(RequirementType) FOR RequirementName IN ([Requirement], [Names], [Go], [Here])) AS pivtable
WHERE [Requirement], [Names], [Go], [Here] IN (
    SELECT RequirementName FROM Requirements WHERE RequirementID IN (
        SELECT Requirement_ID FROM PositionRequirements WHERE Position_ID IN (
            SELECT PositionID FROM Positions WHERE PositionName LIKE '%Manager%')));
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `WHERE [Requirement], [Names], [Go], [Here] in..` just `WHERE [Requirement] in..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PIVOT` query is not arranged properly. Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
      PositionName,
      RequirementType,
      RequirementName 
FROM [Position Requirements] A 
LEFT JOIN Positions B ON A.Position_ID=B.PositionID 
LEFT JOIN Requirements C ON A.Requirement_ID=C.RequirementID
WHERE PositionName LIKE '%Manager%'
) AS TABLE
PIVOT(MAX(RequirementType) FOR RequirementName IN ([Requirement],[Names],[Go],[Here])AS pvt
```

Comment: Brilliant! That is what I was after. Now, I think from what I've read so far, I'd need to build up a bit of T-SQL in order to dynamically generate the RequirementNames list for the PIVOT, correct?